# XSL-FO table center

Tags: xsl-fo, apache-fop

currently I am working on the XSL-FO for generating the PDF files. Infact I am directly writing the FO object instead of separating the XML and XSL. That is our requirement currently. We are able to align the text properly. But, when we are making the table, while keeping it in center not showing the complete table. What could be the problem. Here I am posting the code I have tried:

```
<fo:block>
            <fo:table width="80%"
                border-style="solid"
                border-width="1pt"
                border-color="#69468D"
                table-layout="fixed"
                space-before="10px"
                space-after="10px"
                text-align="start">
                <fo:table-header line-height="10pt"
                    font-size="6pt"
                    background-color="#69468D"
                    color="white"
                    padding-top="3pt">
                    <fo:table-row>
                        <fo:table-cell border-top-color="solid pruple" border-left-color="solid pruple" border="1pt solid white">
                            <fo:block>text</fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell border="0.5pt solid pruple" padding="4pt">
                            <fo:block>text</fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell border="0.5pt solid pruple" padding="4pt">
                            <fo:block>text</fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell border="0.5pt solid pruple" padding="4pt">
                            <fo:block>text</fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell border="0.5pt solid pruple" padding="4pt">
                            <fo:block>text</fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell border="0.5pt solid pruple" padding="4pt">
                            <fo:block>Text</fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                    </fo:table-row>
                </fo:table-header>
                <fo:table-body line-height="5pt"
                    font-size="6pt">
                    <fo:table-row padding-top="3pt">
                        <fo:table-cell text-align="center">
                            <fo:block> 
                                hi
                            </fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell text-align="center">
                            <fo:block> 
                            hi
                            </fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                    </fo:table-row>
                </fo:table-body>
            </fo:table>
        </fo:block>
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the solution would be absolute measurements instead of percentage.

Answer (score 1):

If we have five columns then we can center table as follows

```
<fo:table width="100%">
    <fo:table-column column-width="20%"/>
    <fo:table-column column-width="20%"/>
    <fo:table-column column-width="20%"/>
    <fo:table-column column-width="20%"/>
    <fo:table-column column-width="20%"/>
</fo:table>
```