# How to center table in xsl-fo?

Tags: css, xml, xslt, xsl-fo

I am trying to center a table in a block element in a xsl-fo namespace.

Here is what I am trying:

```
 <fo:block margin-right="auto" margin-left="auto" background-color="#eaeaea">
     <fo:table margin-top="1cm" margin-left="auto" margin-right="auto" margin-bottom="1cm" width="auto">
```

And this is the output:

[image]

How can I center this table in this block?

Thank you.

Comment: I am not familiar with xsl-fo but would align="center" inside the tags not work?

Comment: I tried: <fo:table margin-top="1cm" margin-left="auto" margin-right="auto" margin-bottom="1cm" width="auto" display-align="center"> but did not work. @SimonStaton

Comment: Which XSL-FO processor are you using?

Comment: Do you use FOP? If so, this might help: http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/fo.html#fo-center-table-horizon.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Per the specification, a `<table>` is centred by using `text-align="center"` on a parent `<table-and-caption>` element.  The `<table-caption>` sibling is optional and can be omitted such that the table is the only child.

Note this will not work by putting `text-align` on a parent `<block>` ... a child `<table>` is still a block-level construct and is not affected.  It has to be on the parent `<table-and-caption>`.

I remind my XSL-FO students that they likely will want a `text-align="start"` on their `<table>` unless they also want the contents of the table to be centred due to the inheritance of the property on descendant constructs.

I should note a postscript based on my commercial work  that not all XSL-FO processors support the specification in this regard.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When I add table-caption like:  <fo:table-and-caption text-align="center"><fo:table margin-top="1cm" text-align="start"> my table gets totally lost.. Why might this be?

Comment: This seems to be related to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12119172/xsl-fo-table-center?rq=1) question which is still unanswered.

Comment: My guess is that your processor is non-conformant.  I use a conformant processor to solve my cusotmers' problems.  Good luck ... my guess is that you may be out of options.

Comment: FOP does not support <fo:table-and-caption>. See http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/compliance.html#fo-object-table-and-caption

Answer (score 2):

If using Apache FOP, they explain a table centering technique here:
https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/fo.html#fo-center-table-horizon

Comment: What is the difference between xsl-fo and Apache Fop?

Comment: @KorayTugay as I just found out, Apache FOP does not support 100% of xsl-fo properties: https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/compliance.html

Comment: This technique does work, but it's an unpleasant hack to nest the table you want inside another one that controls the horizontal layout.

Answer (score 1):

If we have **ten** columns then we can center table as follows

```html
<fo:table width="100%">
  <fo:table-column column-width="10%">
  <fo:table-column column-width="10%">
  <fo:table-column column-width="10%">
  <fo:table-column column-width="10%">
  <fo:table-column column-width="10%">
  <fo:table-column column-width="10%">
  <fo:table-column column-width="10%">
  <fo:table-column column-width="10%">
  <fo:table-column column-width="10%">
  <fo:table-column column-width="10%">
 </fo:table>
```

Comment: That doesn't center the table, it just makes it as wide as the enclosing block (usually the text column).

Answer (score -1):

you can simply add styles right to the xsl page!

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms764661(v=vs.85)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).